# How to tranponse the DATE column and show total_cases per country?

Tags: r, date, transpose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxhr.png)

This column DATE shows covid cases for different times during the year for each country hence there is too many observation. I want to flip the DATE column horizontally so that the location stays the same and for each country there is only one row but still shows the same data.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`, along with data of what the solution should produce. do not use pictures!

Comment: You want e.g. pivot_wider.

Comment: @mnist sorry Its my 2nd day using stackoverflow.

Comment: Dont just say you are sorry, but please also EDIT your question. See the link provided by mnist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Or, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** OP: New requirement: see comments:
Now we could combine `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# set seed and randomly generate numbers for example dataframe
set.seed(123)
df %>% 
    mutate(total_deaths = sample.int(100, 13, replace = TRUE),
           total_vaccinations = sample.int(100, 13, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(total_cases, total_deaths, total_vaccinations), 
        names_to = "total",
        values_to = "value"
    ) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = DATE, 
        values_from = value
    )
```

output:

```
 location    total              `2020-02-24` `2020-02-25` `2020-02-26` `2020-02-27` `2020-02-28` `2020-02-29` `2020-03-01` `2020-03-02` `2020-03-03` `2020-03-04` `2020-03-05` `2020-03-06` `2020-03-07`
  <chr>       <chr>                     <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1 Afghanistan total_cases                   1            1            1            1            1            1            1            1            2            4            4            4            4
2 Afghanistan total_deaths                 25           87           90           32           84           24           57           73           23           14            6           91            1
3 Afghanistan total_vaccinations           90           58           81           29           26           27           85            7           60           26           41           84            6
```

As @deschen already mentioned you need `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = DATE,
        values_from = total_cases
    )
```

Output:

```
  location    `2020-02-24` `2020-02-25` `2020-02-26` `2020-02-27` `2020-02-28` `2020-02-29` `2020-03-01` `2020-03-02` `2020-03-03` `2020-03-04` `2020-03-05` `2020-03-06` `2020-03-07`
  <chr>              <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1 Afghanistan            1            1            1            1            1            1            1            1            2            4            4            4            4
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(location = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"
), DATE = c("2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", 
"2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", 
"2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-07"), total_cases = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot  @TarJae - now if I want to get the same for more variables. for. ex if i after total_cases, I have total_deaths, total_vaccinations and so on. And now I want to create for each of them a separate variable like I did for total_deaths. Should I write a function to do that or manually?

Comment: Is it always one country?

Comment: nope there are 233 countries.

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jeQCyQjCygOJSBm7hu2yeSa_vGDQapm9jLMl3Yt4KhI/edit?usp=sharing I am using these data

Comment: The code works with your dataset!